# Quartz jobs - disallow concurrent execution group-wide?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

using Quartz, I'd like few jobs (say about 10) to execute as a chain - i.e. NOT concurrently.
They should be executed after an "accounting day change" event occur but since they all access the same DB, I dont want them to start all together. I want them to be executed sequentially instead (order doesnt matter).

I have an idea to put them into a group - say "account_day_change_jobs" and configure Quartz somehow to do the rest for me :-) Means - run sequentially all jobs from the group. I tried the API doc (both 1.8 and 2.1), tried google but didnt find anything.

Is it possible? Is it even reasonable? Other ideas how to achieve the behavior I want?

Thanks very much for any ideas :-)
Hans

Answer (score 2):

The Trigger Listener class below should re-schedule any jobs that attempt to execute while another job that the listener has been configured for is running.
Ive only lightly tested it but for simple cases it should be suitable.

```
public class SequentialTriggerListener extends TriggerListenerSupport {

private JobKey activeJob;
private Scheduler activeScheduler;
private Queue<JobDetail> queuedJobs = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<JobDetail>();

public String getName() {
    return "SequentialTriggerListener";
}

public boolean vetoJobExecution(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (activeJob != null) {
            getLog().debug("Queueing Sequential Job - " + context.getJobDetail().getKey().getName());
            JobDetail jd = context.getJobDetail();
            activeScheduler = context.getScheduler();
            jd = JobBuilder.newJob().usingJobData(jd.getJobDataMap()).withIdentity(getName() + ":" + jd.getKey().getName(), jd.getKey().getGroup())
                    .ofType(jd.getJobClass()).build();
            queuedJobs.add(jd);
            return true;
        } else {
            activeJob = trigger.getJobKey();
            getLog().debug("Executing Job - " + activeJob.getName());
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public void triggerMisfired(Trigger trigger) {
    triggerFinalized(trigger);
}

public void triggerComplete(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context, CompletedExecutionInstruction triggerInstructionCode) {
    triggerFinalized(trigger);
}

protected void triggerFinalized(Trigger trigger) {
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            if (trigger.getJobKey().equals(activeJob)) {
                getLog().debug("Finalized Sequential Job - " + activeJob.getName());
                activeJob = null;
                JobDetail jd = queuedJobs.poll();
                if (jd != null) {
                    getLog().debug("Triggering Sequential Job - " + jd.getKey().getName());
                    activeScheduler.scheduleJob(jd,TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(jd).withIdentity("trigger:" + jd.getKey().getName(), jd.getKey().getGroup())
                            .startNow().withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withRepeatCount(0).withIntervalInMilliseconds(1)).build());
                }
            } else {
                // this should not occur as the trigger finalizing should be the one we are tracking.
                getLog().warn("Sequential Trigger Listener execution order failer");
            }
        } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
            getLog().warn("Sequential Trigger Listener failure", ex);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

its has been a long time since I used quartz, however I would try two [job listeners](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/JobListeners) registered to listen to two different groups

the basic idea is to have one job fire from a group / list ("todayGroup"), the '("todayGroup") job listener detects the completion for good or bad. then kicks off the next job in the list.  However, it saves the 'just finished' job back in the scheduler under the ("tomorrowGroup").

```
public class MyTodayGroupListener extends JobListenerSupport {

    private String name;

    private static String GROUP_NAME = "todayGroup";

    public MyOtherJobListener(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }


    @Override
    public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context,
        JobExecutionException jobException) {
        Scheduler sched = context.getScheduler();
        // switch the job to the other group so we don't run it again today.
        JobDetail current = context.getJobDetail();
        JobDetail tomorrows  = current.getJobBuilder().withIdentity(current.getKey().getName(), "tomorrow").build();
        sched.addJob(tomorrows,true);

        //see if there is anything left to run
        Set<JobKey> jobKeys = sched.getJobKeys(groupEquals(GROUP_NAME ));
        Iterator<JobKey> nextJob = null;
        if(jobKeys != null && !jobKeys.isEmpty() ){
            nextJob = jobKeys.iterator();
        }
        if(nextJob != null){
            // Define a Trigger that will fire "now" and associate it with the first job from the list
            Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .startNow()
                .forJob(nextJob =.next())
                .build();

            // Schedule the trigger
            sched.scheduleJob(trigger);
        }

    }
}
```

likewise, you'll need two 'group triggers' that will fire the first job from their respective groups at the given time you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TriggerGroupDisallowConcurrentExecutionTriggerListener : ITriggerListener
{
    private IScheduler activeScheduler;
    private readonly object locker = new object();
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, JobsQueueInfo> groupsDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, JobsQueueInfo>();

    public string Name => "TriggerGroupDisallowConcurrentExecutionTriggerListener";

    public Task TriggerComplete(ITrigger trigger, IJobExecutionContext context, SchedulerInstruction triggerInstructionCode, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        //JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;
        //Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: TriggerComplete. {key.Name} - {key.Group} - {trigger.Key.Name}");

        TriggerFinished(trigger, cancellationToken);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task TriggerFired(ITrigger trigger, IJobExecutionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        //JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;
        //Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: TriggerFired. {key.Name} - {key.Group} - {trigger.Key.Name}");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task TriggerMisfired(ITrigger trigger, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        //JobKey key = trigger.JobKey;
        //Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: TriggerMisfired. {key.Name} - {key.Group} - {trigger.Key.Name}");

        TriggerFinished(trigger, cancellationToken);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task<bool> VetoJobExecution(ITrigger trigger, IJobExecutionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        //JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;
        //Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: VetoJobExecution. {key.Name} - {key.Group} - {trigger.Key.Name}");

        lock (locker)
        {
            //if (!groupsDictionary.ContainsKey(context.JobDetail.Key.Group))
            //{
            groupsDictionary.TryAdd(context.JobDetail.Key.Group, new JobsQueueInfo { QueuedJobs = new ConcurrentQueue<IJobDetail>(), ActiveJobKey = null });
            var activeJobKey = groupsDictionary[context.JobDetail.Key.Group].ActiveJobKey;
            //}

            if (activeJobKey != null && activeJobKey != context.JobDetail.Key)
            {
                var queuedJobs = groupsDictionary[context.JobDetail.Key.Group].QueuedJobs;
                if (queuedJobs.Any(jobDetail => jobDetail.Key.Name == context.JobDetail.Key.Name) == true)
                {
                    //NOTE: Джоба уже есть в очереди, нет необходимости её добавлять повторно
                    return Task.FromResult(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    //NOTE: Добавить джобу в очередь на выполнение, и не выполнять её сейчас, т.к. она будет выполнена как только подойдёт её очередь
                    activeScheduler = context.Scheduler;
                    var newJob = JobBuilder.Create(context.JobDetail.JobType).WithIdentity(context.JobDetail.Key).Build();
                    queuedJobs.Enqueue(newJob);

                    return Task.FromResult(true);
                }
            }

            groupsDictionary[context.JobDetail.Key.Group].ActiveJobKey = trigger.JobKey;

            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }

    protected void TriggerFinished(ITrigger trigger, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!groupsDictionary.ContainsKey(trigger.JobKey.Group))
                {
                    return;
                }

                var queuedJobs = groupsDictionary[trigger.JobKey.Group].QueuedJobs;
                if (queuedJobs.TryDequeue(out IJobDetail jobDetail))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine($"dequeue - {jobDetail.Key.Name}");

                    var task = activeScheduler.TriggerJob(jobDetail.Key, cancellationToken);
                    task.ConfigureAwait(false);
                    task.Wait(cancellationToken);

                    groupsDictionary[trigger.JobKey.Group].ActiveJobKey = jobDetail.Key;
                }
                else
                {
                    groupsDictionary[trigger.JobKey.Group].ActiveJobKey = null;
                }
            }
            catch (SchedulerException ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    private class JobsQueueInfo
    {

        public ConcurrentQueue<IJobDetail> QueuedJobs { get; set; }

        public JobKey ActiveJobKey { get; set; }
    }
}
```